# grep multiline shell variable from output of executable file

Tags: bash, shell, sh, ksh

I'm trying to grep lines from a execution output with a multi-line shell variable, but I'm not quite sure how to do it
for example, if I execute a file named *run* and the result is:

```
blahblah aaa
blahblah bbb
blabhblasd ccc
----------- ddd
...

blah blah  ggg
```

and so on. And then, I have a shell variable, which is a another result from grep (and is multiline), for example
$VAR holds

```
aaa
bbb
ggg
```

I want to grep this $VAR from the result of *run*, so I have the result

```
blahblah aaa
blahblah bbb
blah blah  ggg
```

I tried something like

run | grep "VAR"
but I'm not quite getting the result I want. Is there any way to grep multi-line variable from a execution output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
run | grep -f <(printf '%s\n' "$var")
```

- It prints any line of the `run` output that matches any line in the `$var` variable.
- See [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) in the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) for an explanation of `<(printf '%s\n' "$var")`.
- See the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812) for an explanation of why I used `printf` instead of `echo` to output the contents of `$var`.
- See [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/4154375) for an explanation of why I used `$var` instead of `$VAR`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file
blahblah aaa
blahblah bbb
blabhblasd ccc
----------- ddd
...

blah blah  ggg
```

```
$ echo "$var"
aaa
bbb
ggg
```

```
$ cat file | awk -v var="$var" 'BEGIN{split(var,tmp); for (i in tmp) arr[tmp[i]]} $NF in arr'
blahblah aaa
blahblah bbb
blah blah  ggg
```

Replace `cat file` with `run`.